# Programmatically regenerate keys for group enrollments in Azure Device provisioning Service (DPS)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, provisioning, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I want to programmatically regenerate the symmetric key (primary and secondary keys) in group enrollments of Azure DPS, there is an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/service/enrollment-group) provided by azure in the link.
I used this [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/provisioning/service/src/ProvisioningServiceClient.cs) and was able to run it.

I used the API but it retured 404 not found.
I used the mentioned [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/provisioning/service/src/ProvisioningServiceClient.cs) and was able to get the instance of an enrollment group.
Now I want a way to regenerate the keys for current group but there is seem to have no function that would allow that thing.
A way is to change the redo attestation that in return will change the symmetric keys but I have not find a way yet.

If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There's no API specifically for regenerating group enrollment keys. However, you can use the **CreateOrUpdateEnrollmentGroupAsync** method to update an existing enrollment group, passing in a new set of keys. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.provisioningserviceclient.createorupdateenrollmentgroupasync?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-preview
You will need to generate your new symmetric keys to pass in as part of the **EnrollmentGroup** parameter.

The following sample shows an example of using this method with an enrollment group that uses X.509 certs, but you should be able to easily modify it to use symmetric keys instead: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/main/provisioning/service/samples/getting%20started/EnrollmentGroupSample

To generate a suitable key in Python, you could use the following:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from base64 import b64encode
s = 'mysecretkeyfordps'
h = sha256()
h.update(s.encode())
b64bytes = b64encode(h.digest())
print(b64bytes.decode())
```

Comment: Hi Dominic thanks for this help, I have tried it but now the issue is I am not able to create my set of symmetric keys and add them to my enrollment group, every time I try to change the keys I get this error:  "attestation can only be x502 certificate or symmetric keys." Can you help me with creating new sets of symmetric keys that would be accepted by enrollment group?

Comment: I'm not sure what programming language you're using, but I'll add an example piece of Python code you could use to the answer.